# how to retrieve all named properties of a Freebase type?

Tags: freebase, mql

I'm trying to get a list of all properties for each Freebase type, basically to display the same schema for a certain type as you can find on the Freebase webpage.

I just can't understand how to do this in MQL. Most examples I can find are targeted to get the ***data*** that is inside the properties, but I'm interested in the schema only.

For example, for

```
/comic_books/comic_book_character
```

I want to display:

```
Primary Universe
Created by
First Appearance
Story Specific Appearances
Regular Featured Appearances
Cover Appearances
```

http://www.freebase.com/comic_books/comic_book_character

Anyone who could help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get that information is from the [Topic API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview). Just plug the type ID into the API request URL like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/02hqb47?filter=/type/type
```